# JWrapper "unpack200.exe not found"

Tags: java, jwrapper

I am creating an `.exe` file using `JWrapper` in Windows and getting this exception:

> java.lang.Exception: unpack200.exe not found in Windows JRE bin path

From the command line I can execute `unpack200.exe`. How do I resolve the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue when I was adding the JREs to use JWrapper in order to wrap my app. I assume you followed the instructions on the "[Getting Started](http://www.jwrapper.com/getting-started.html)" guide.

The issue I had was that the downloaded tar.gz would extract the directory `jre-8u60-windows-x64`, however that directory contains another sub-directory which is named `jre1.8.0_60`, where the bin and lib directories are located - `unpack200.exe` is located in bin under the second level dir.

Pointing JWrapper to the JRE directory `jre-8u60-windows-x64` would give me the same error you encountered while pointing to `jre-8u60-windows-x64/jre1.8.0_60` solved the issue for me; the same logic was applied to all the other JREs I downloaded.

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @autronix. Have another problem. Would you help on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071913/jwrapper-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-malformed Thanks