# JWrapper "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED"

Tags: java, jwrapper

In the step of adding the my jar file to the build process, there is this error:

```
[Archive] Adding file (33065030) (ioc2-config.jar) E:\WORK\NETBEANS\ioc2-config_v2015-09\store\ioc2-config.jar
[Archive] Will pack200 ioc2-config.jar
**********************************
*          BUILD FAILED          *
**********************************
** Error Trace:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
.....
** Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
```

The jar file is working perfectly. What can I do?

Thanks.